# Adder-Subtractor Circuit With Negative Results

Tags: arithmetic

So, I understand how binary arithmetic works, and I understand how an adder-subtractor works for signed numbers. There is only one thing I am not sure about:

All the cases work ok in the circuit I have, except if the result of a subtraction is negative, I need to take the two's complement of the output byte to get the actual result. What can I do about it? Do I need an extra array of adders to compute the two's complement only in that specific way, or is there any smarter solution I can apply?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing your circuit diagram.

Comment: (Back in the day, a *"carry" input* was used for the lowest significant bit, too: you get to choose the value.)

Answer (score 1):

(Can't leave a comment, unfortunately.)

I'm having the same issue. Here's the diagram (sorry, it's messy):

[image]

I've also found this on the web:

> The algorithm to subtract two binary numbers using 2’s complement is
> explained as following below −
>
> - Take 2’s complement of the subtrahend
> - Add with minuend
> - If the result of above addition has carry bit 1, then it is dropped and this result will be positive number.
> - If there is no carry bit 1, then take 2’s complement of the result which will be negative